# How to parse variable child nodes with Gson?

Tags: json, gson, android

Apologies for the confusing title, could not come up with a better one.

My API returns a response like this :

```
{
    "type":"a",
    "extras":{
        "a1":"valueA1",
        "a2":"valueA2"
    }
}
```

If the type is "b", then response is like :

```
{
    "extras":{
        "b1":"valueB1"
    },
    "type":"b"     //note that "type" may come after "extras"
}
```

For a third type "c", response can be :

```
{
    "type":"c",
    "extras":{
        "b1":"valueB1",
        "a1":"valueA1",
        "a2":"valueA2"
    }
}
```

Following are my requirements :

1. There are over 20 such "types" which the API can return.
2. Each type has an extra node with attributes which may or may not be shared with other typeExtras. Typically 1-10 attributes in each extra node.
3. Order of "type" and "extras" is not fixed. But both are guaranteed to be present.

The naive solution I am trying is to have one "extras" POJO with all possible attribute values :
**Extras.java**

```
String a1;
String a2;
String b1;
```

My clients have checks like this during consumption:

```
if(type.isA()) {
    a1 = extras.a1;
    a2 = extras.a2;
    //there is no way to prevent developers from calling extras.b1
}
```

My code is bloated with over 50 attributes and littered with null checks for 20 types. Is there a better way ?

**Bonus question :** I strongly feel that the API is poorly designed. Are there any second thoughts ?

Comment: **1.** `extras.b1` will be found in type `b` and `c` right? **2.** Each response type (a,b,c) has a particular set of extras, i mean fixed set of values?.

Comment: 1. I just gave a random example. extras.b1 could be in a or b or c or all (depending on what API wants to return). 2. Think of extras as a map; it can have any number of keys. I have a list of ALL possible keys, but I don't know which keys are present in the current extra.